# Sort an array on three variables

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array with playing cards. I would like to sort these on value, color and playability.

- I have 4 colors; 1, 2, 3, 4.
- I have 3 playability options; 1, 2, 3.
- I have 5 values; 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I am able to sort the array on color and value. So if the color is the same, the array is sorted on value.

example color-value pairs:

```
1-2, 1-4, 1-5, 2-2, 3-1, 3-2, 3-5
```

Code is,

```
playerCards.sort {
       if $0.colorSorter == $1.colorSorter {
            return $0.value < $1.value
       }
        return $0.colorSorter < $1.colorSorter
    }
```

How do I add the third paramater to sort on playability additionally?

What I would like to see (playability-color-value triplets):

```
1-1-2, 1-1-4, 1-2-2, 1-3-1, 2-1-5, 2-3-1, 2-3-2, 3-3-5
```

1: sort on playability
2: sort on color
3: sort on value.

Thanks!

Comment: http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/sort-descriptors-in-swift/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is your struct

```
struct Card {
    let color:Int
    let value:Int
    let playability:Int
}
```

and this is your array

```
let cards:[Card] = ...
```

You can sort `cards` by

1. `playability`
2. `color`
3. `value`

writing

```
let sorted = cards.sorted { (left, right) -> Bool in
    guard left.playability == right.playability else { return left.playability < right.playability }
    guard left.color == right.color else { return left.color < right.color }
    return left.value < right.value
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!